# Implement Calender sync functionality in Android

Tags: android, android-calendar

I am developing an app to get the android calender synced with my calender present on server as I have found there is an Account Manager API that can sync calender and contacts on your device but I am zero about how it can be implemented how we can make a calender on server so that it will automatically sync with calender present on android device can you help me to have an idea for both server and client implementation if possible please share some sample of code so I can have the picture of syncing process in my mind.

Is really the account manager api do what I need or do I need to some different approach to acquire the same ?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a sync adapter that manages the synchronization between your server and the Android devices.

See the [Sample SyncAdapter project](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/) to get the idea of a sync adapter.

I've written a blog post on [how to use Android's CalendarContract content provider](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/androids-calendarcontract-provider/) and there is also a [good guide on Android's site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html) about it that also briefly touches sync adapters.

The [AccountManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) API is needed to create an account on the device which can then be used to log onto your server.